# Kafka-connect file sink connector write in parquet file format

Tags: apache-kafka, parquet, apache-kafka-connect

I am looking for kafka-connect connector that will write from kafka to local file system in parquet file format.
I don't want to use the hdfs or s3 sink connector for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format.class=ParquetFormat` only exists in the mentioned connectors

You can use `file://` prefix to write to local disk, or use a project like MinIO to reproduce self-hosted S3

Comment: Will this work without specifying hdfs server details if I use hdfs connector or without s3 host details if I use s3 connector.

Comment: Rather than a namenode, you can set `store.uri` as a `file://` path; I don't think you need any other configs like Hadoop XML files (it's been a while since I tried it). For the S3 connector, you do need those details. Like I said, you can use MinIO, for example - https://blog.min.io/kafka_and_minio/

Comment: So I have used minio, able to write data to minio using kafka-connect-s3 connector.

Comment: I have asked another question related to hdfs, see if you can help me there as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943956/not-able-to-connect-to-hadoop-server-using-hadoopfilesystem-in-pyarrrow